# Rust: Cargo.toml error: expected item, found `[`, when trying to include nalgebra

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
[package]
name = "my package"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
nalgebra = "0.18.1"
```

I tried to compile rust with above Cargo.toml but it gave me following error:

```
error: expected item, found `[`
 --> Cargo.toml:1:1
  |
1 | [package]
  | ^ expected item

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I can fix this if I remove `nalgebra = "0.18.1"`, but I can't use `nalgebra` package so it doesn't help me.

Comment: It looks like you (or your IDE) incorrectly ran `rustc Cargo.toml` instead of `cargo run` or whatever. (`expected item, found ...` is a rustc error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error disappeared after closing the cargo.toml file which was opened on the visual studio.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with `Cargo.lock` getting a lock on the `Cargo.toml`?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are multiple issues with your Cargo.toml

This is not allowed:

```
name = "my package"
```

Suggestion:

```
name = "my-package"
```

There is also missing parts:

```
error during execution of `cargo metadata`: error: failed to parse manifest at `test/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  no targets specified in the manifest
  either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
```

Could you post the entire file here?

A minimum viable setup:

```
[package]
name = "my-package"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me"]
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "radkilla"
path = "src/main.rs"
doc = false

[dependencies]
nalgebra = "0.18.1"
```

src/main.rs

```
fn main() {}
```

Running fmt and build:

```
➜  test cargo fmt ; cargo build
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.11s
```

Comment: A `[[bin]]` section isn't required if you have a `src/main.rs` file - Cargo will pick that up automatically.